# Why am I getting this error when I call a function from another file?

Tags: python

I need help.  I have a main file, and I have another file named main_func.py in a folder called functions, which is in a folder called resources.  It worked before, but now it doesn't.  This is the code...

```
from Resources.functions import main_func
....

def Main():
    conversionprocess()
    ....
```

Then in the main_func file I have this...

```
def conversionprocess():
    Clear()
    print(cyan, 'The available units include miles, kilometers, meters, millimeters, centimeters, 
    inches, yards, and feet.\n\n')
    whattoconvert = input('What unit would you like to convert? PLEASE ANSWER WITH NO CAPITAL 
    LETTERS!:\n')
    ....
```

But it raises and error:

```
NameError: name 'conversionprocess' is not defined
```

Can someone please help me with this??
Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.python.org/3.9/tutorial/modules.html to learn more about how to use modules and packages.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
  main_func.conversionprocess()
```

Comment: upvoted for not suggesting `from Resources.functions.main_func import *`

Comment: I still get an error that says partially initialized module

Comment: @SxolarBit - That's a different problem and could be a new question here on stackoverflow. But do some searching first - its likely a circular import (and perhaps executing some module level code) and there are already a lot of answers to that problem.

Comment: yep that's what it said sorry for not including that I fixed the problem by putting the code in main_func.py, and putting it in the main file.